# iOS Swift Error: 'T' is not convertible to 'MirrorDisposition'

Tags: swift, ios8

I am attempting to create an extension method for the Array type to allow for removing an item from an array

```
extension Array {
    func remove(item: AnyObject) {
        for var i = self.count - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
            if self[i] == item {
                self.removeAtIndex(i)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the test condition `if self[i] == item`, I get the following error: `'T' is not convertible to 'MirrorDisposition'`

I've tried many different things, which include:

- Using generics: `remove<T>(item: T)`
- Using the `===` operator, which just gives the error `'T' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'`

I'm new to Swift, so this is where my knowledge runs out. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting an error because the compiler can't guarantee that the element stored in your array can be compared with `==`. You have to ensure that it the contained type is `Equatable`. However, there is no way to add a method to a generic class that is more restrictive than the class itself. It is better to implement it as a function:

```
func removeItem<T: Equatable>(item: T, var fromArray array: [T]) -> [T] {
    for i in reverse(0 ..< array.count) {
        if array[i] == item {
            array.removeAtIndex(i)
        }
    }
    return array
}
```

Or you could add it as a more generic extension:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func removeObjectsPassingTest(test: (object: T) -> Bool) {
        for var i : Int = self.count - 1; i >= 0; --i {
            if test(object: self[i]) {
                self.removeAtIndex(i)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
var list: [Int] = [1,2,3,2,1]
list.removeObjectsPassingTest({$0 == 2})
```

Comment: + 1 for the generic extension, it works more in-line with the other functions available on Array: `filter`, `map`, etc.

Comment: You cannot call a `mutating` method (`removeAtIndex`) on a constant (`array`)

Comment: @newacct yes, that is true, how is that relevant?

Comment: @drewag: That's what you did in your first code sample before you edited it. You now changed it to `var`, which is probably not what you want because then only the local copy of the array in the function is changed.

Comment: @newacct, ya I changed it to return the modified array. Thanks for pointing out the constant array issue.

Comment: @drewag: oh right you return it. Though you could also make it `inout` and not have to return it.

Comment: @newacct ya I considered that, but i prefer to make the function more "functional" (pun unavoidable). Plus `inout` feels dirty to me

Answer (score 2):

The way I would write this function is like this:

```
mutating func remove<U where U : Equatable>(item: U) {
    for var i = self.count - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        if self[i] as U == item {
            self.removeAtIndex(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Be sure to decorate your function with mutating.

I would use a different type parameter U since you can't really change Array's type parameter to be Equatable. Then I would try to cast the items to U to do the comparison.

Of course, this will fail if you try to call this function with an Array that is instantiated with a non-equatable type.

Comment: Important note, with this implementation, the compiler will not complain if you pass a type that doesn't match the type contained in array, but it will crash at runtime because the `as` conversion will fail. Better to at least make that an optional casting.

Comment: @MariánČerný: you cannot form a range with end < start

Comment: @newacct Makes sense. I will delete my note not to confuse people.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution but if you are trying to remove an item from an array, this is how I do it:

`var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
if let possibleIndex = find(numbers, 1) {
    numbers.removeAtIndex(possibleIndex)
}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is MirrorDispsition, but I think the problem is that you can't always equate two objects in Array, because they are not guaranteed to be equatable.

Edit: Look at tng's solution. It will only work with equatable items, though.

Comment: If I understand the '===' operator correctly, it would compare whether the two items reference the same object, not whether the objects value's are equal. So, I'm not sure why '===' is not working.

Comment: “AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type.”

..and the object from the array does not have to be AnyObject (instance of a class type). It can be a closure, struct, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is confusing. The problem why it does not work is because Swift compiler can not find `==` operator for Array's element type `T`. For this to work `T` would need to conform to `Equatable` protocol.